# How to convert hexadecimal value to signed decimal equivalent in C#?

Tags: c#

Example :

Hexadecimal :ebe4fe40

Signed decimal :-337314240

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is this:

> yourHexNumber ──> String ──> ConvertIntoDecimal

This will convert from hexadecimal to decimal:

```
 string myHexNumber = "ebe4fe40";
 int decValue = Convert.ToInt32(myHexNumber, 16); // This will be -337314240
```

To convert from decimal to hexadecimal you will do this:

```
int decValue = -337314240;
string myHexNumber = decValue.ToString("X"); // This will be EBE4FE40
```

This method is shorter, so I like it more.

Comment: thanks for your reply ...but the output for this method is decimal = 3957653056  . i have used the same method for conversion  but i need signed decimal ???

Comment: @ john  !!!!! sorry bro  method was correct .. i got the output  thanks 4 the help

Answer (score 2):

To convert from Hex to Decimal...

```
int decValue = int.Parse(hexValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```